# Using Pig on Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I've been trying to use CurrentTime() on the sandbox provided by Hortonworks and can't get it to work.

This is all I have in the Pig script:

```
<code>
REGISTER zookeeper.jar
REGISTER piggybank.jar
REGISTER hbase-common-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar
REGISTER hbase-common-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2-tests.jar
REGISTER hbase-client-0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2.jar
REGISTER guava.jar
a = CurrentTime();
dump a;
</code>
```

The error I see in the logs say:

```
15/04/13 21:23:22 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
15/04/13 21:23:22 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
15/04/13 21:23:22 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2015-04-13 21:23:22,428 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041 (rexported) compiled Nov 19 2014, 15:24:46
2015-04-13 21:23:22,429 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/appcache/application_1428957295391_0006/container_1428957295391_0006_01_000002/pig_1428960202427.log
2015-04-13 21:23:24,041 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/yarn/.pigbootup not found
2015-04-13 21:23:24,615 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020
2015-04-13 21:23:27,864 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file script.pig, line 10> Cannot expand macro 'CurrentTime'. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.
Failed to parse: <file script.pig, line 10> Cannot expand macro 'CurrentTime'. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.
    at org.apache.pig.parser.PigMacro.macroInline(PigMacro.java:455)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.inlineMacro(QueryParserDriver.java:301)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.expandMacro(QueryParserDriver.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:183)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1735)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1443)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:398)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:741)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:495)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
2015-04-13 21:23:27,871 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file script.pig, line 10> Cannot expand macro 'CurrentTime'. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.
Details at logfile: /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/appcache/application_1428957295391_0006/container_1428957295391_0006_01_000002/pig_1428960202427.log
2015-04-13 21:23:27,908 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 5 seconds and 684 milliseconds (5684 ms)
```

I included those register lines since I thought maybe the UDFs weren't somehow included. I have no idea what to do now

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use complete path of the method current time. I have an example below where I am converting a **given time into unix date format.**

```
register '/usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar' ;
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix();

date_filter = FOREACH parsed_log GENERATE ISOToUnix(date) AS unixTime:long;
 STORE date_filter INTO '/root/pig/output/parselogdate/';
```

I think for your application you have to use below, just try if it works. Your currenttime will take tuple as input and return current time as output.

```
//Users is a file with tuples in it.
     a = load users;
     b = foreach a generate org.apache.pig.builtin.CurrentTime(); 
     dump b;
```

I tried executing above and got output. You can find [java doc](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/index.html?org/apache/pig/builtin/CurrentTime.html).

Comment: So in the Hortonworks Sandbox, they have some UDFs that I can include. When I click on the piggbank.jar UDF to include it, the text `REGISTER piggybank.jar` is automatically added. I add in 2 more lines to make it `REGISTER piggybank.jar; a = CurrentTime();
dump a;` However I'm still getting the same `Cannot expand macro` error

Comment: Check my latest edit above it should work. You cannot CurrentTime() directly, it should be executed on each tuple.